# DigitalOcean Droplet not serving django app with python runserver command

Tags: digital-ocean, python-3.10, django-4.0, ubuntu-22.04

i know i have seen similar questions on the issue but most of them seemed to be solved by allowing the port 8000 by using the command `sudo ufw allow 8000`. i have tried that but it is still not displaying when i visited my `droplet_ipaddress:8000` link.  i followed the official tutorials https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04.

```
SYSTEM INFORMATION
    OS =  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
    Python  = 3.10
    Django  = 4.0.4
```

the only difference with my work and the project process is that i did not build an dummy django project on my digitalocean vps rather i use git to clone my project repo and did the neccesary dependency installing using pip. Has anyone encountered the same problem and is there any solution.

when ever i ran `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

the output is shown below as expected … but my page doesn't not display as expected

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 33 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): account, accounts, admin, ads, auth, chat, contenttypes, notification, payments, report, sales, sessions, sites, socialaccount.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
May 10, 2022 - 11:41:04
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'ma_mall.settings.production'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.4 development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

when i visit the page its says
[image]

searching for the allowed port on the system gave this
[image]

which clearly shows the the port is now allowed to serve the app

Answer (score 0):

In Digital Ocean, it is possible that you have a second firewall enabled that can be configured directly on the platform. You can find it under `Droplet`>`Networking`. Check if a firewall exists and adjust it for your port. Since two firewalls are a bit cumbersome and pointless, I would recommend using only the Digital Ocean firewalls and disabling ufw permanently via `ufw disable`.

Comment: Thank you very much but this is not the case here... I noticed that creating a dummy Django app with django-admin start project and then setting up the allowed hosted and running server with manage.py made the dummy Django welcome page load on my ip:8000 link but once I tried cloning a real project from GitHub and doing the necessary setup it just didn’t serve or respond to requests..